# dropdown list & php

Tags: php, xml, forms

I am trying to create a drop down list that limits the number of images shown per page and allow the user to decide how many images to show, by default I've set 5   I have tried to search the net I not managed to come up with a solution here is the code I have tried

```
<form action="image_search.php" name="formSize" method="post">  
   <span id="PageSize" style="color:Gray;">Page Size:</span>
   <select name="pagesize">
    <option selected="selected" value="5">5</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
   </select>&nbsp;
  <span id="Title" style="color:Gray;"></span>
</form>
<?php
    include_once("includes/images.php");
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("xml/images.xml"); //load the images
     $page = 0;
       if (isset($_POST['formSize']))
       {
             $varSize = $_POST['pagesize'];
        }
$MAXELEMENTSPERPAGE = $varSize; //change this value to display how many elements per page you wish people to see
 $maxPage = count($xml)/$MAXELEMENTSPERPAGE;

if(isset($_GET['page']))
   {
     $page = $_GET['page'];   //if page is specif
     }
?>
```

if I remove $varSize and replace it with a number it works but as is I get this error
Undefined variable: varSize

Comment: How are you posting the data, where does `formSize` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the user POSTS to the page, varSize must have a value. So define varSize outside your if statement. Then it will change if the user changes it.

```
$varSize = 5;
if (isset($_POST['formSize'])){
    $varSize = $_POST['pagesize'];
}
$MAXELEMENTSPERPAGE = $varSize;
```

Comment: that allowed the page to show properly but the drop down list has now effect on the number of items shown per page

Comment: Then your if statement is wrong. All my code did was give `$varSize` a default value. if `isset($_POST['formSize'])` is true, `$varSize` will be replaced by `$_POST['pagesize']`. It's up to you to determine if `$_POST['formsize']` is in fact set and that `$_POST['pagesize']` has a value other than 5.

Comment: sorry but I am still learning or should I say trying to learn php I found the drop down list on a website and I am trying to incorperate the idea into my project I am not sure how I find what the value of the posted item is can you advise

Comment: I apologize I got confused because some of your variables are camel case and some are not. dump your `$_POST` after you submit the page and see what is there. Try to keep things consistent. Decide now if you are going to do `pageSize` or `pagesize`, `formsize` or `formSize`. This will help you write better code and not make mistakes.

Comment: Your `$_POST` scope will be empty upon the first page load. It only contains data once the form is submitted. So the user has to select a value and click submit on the form, then `$_POST` will contain that data.

Comment: I finally found the answer to my problem and woul like to post it here should any one else have the same problem the answer is <form id="pagesize" action="<?php $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="get">
                    <select class="paginate" name="caption" onchange="this.form.submit()">

Answer (score 0):

> I get this error Undefined variable: varSize

Because it is undefined. Just define it!

```
$varSize = isset($_POST['pagesize']) ? intval($_POST['pagesize']) : 5;
```

Comment: <option caption=4 value=4>4</option>
                        <option caption=5 value=5>5</option>
                        <option caption=10 value=10>10</option>
                        <option caption=25 value=25>25</option>
                    </select>
                </form>   the final part of the puzzel